# '.class' expected error java and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, while-loop

I'm trying to convert this following file of numbers to it's characters, and then printing that. Then, printing it flipped. 
It is an image of Homer Simpson, and currently the first method is getting a "`Homer.java:38: error: '.class' expected`" error at the first return statement.

```
22 40 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 44 45 45 45 46 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 44 46 39 45 46 32 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 40 32 40 32 44 39 34 34 34 34 34 45 46 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 96 44 88 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 96 46 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 47 96 32 96 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 96 46 95 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 40 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 44 32 32 32 44 95 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 124 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 44 45 45 45 46 44 39 111 32 96 46 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 124 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 47 32 111 32 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 41 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 92 32 44 46 32 32 32 32 40 32 32 32 32 32 32 46 95 95 95 95 44 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 92 124 32 92 32 32 32 32 92 95 95 95 95 44 39 32 32 32 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 39 96 39 92 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 95 44 95 95 95 95 44 39 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 92 32 32 44 45 45 32 32 32 32 32 32 44 45 39 32 32 32 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 40 32 67 32 32 32 32 32 44 39 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 96 45 45 39 32 32 46 39 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 124 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 124 32 32 32 124 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 46 79 32 124 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 95 95 124 32 32 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 44 45 39 95 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 47 32 96 76 32 32 32 32 32 96 46 95 32 32 95 44 39 32 32 39 32 96 46 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 47 32 32 32 32 96 45 45 46 46 95 32 32 96 39 44 46 32 32 32 95 92 32 32 96 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 96 45 46 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 47 92 32 32 124 32 96 46 32 40 32 44 92 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 95 47 32 32 96 45 46 95 32 32 47 32 32 92 32 124 45 45 39 32 32 40 32 32 32 32 32 92 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 39 32 32 96 45 46 32 32 32 96 39 32 32 32 32 92 47 92 96 46 32 32 32 96 46 32 32 32 32 41 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 92 32 32 45 104 114 114 45 32 32 32 32 92 32 96 46 32 32 124 32 32 32 32 124 32
```

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Homer{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
      Scanner homerFile = new Scanner(new File("homer2.txt" ));
      Scanner mysteryFile = new Scanner(new File("mystery2.txt" ));
      char[][] arr = makeHomer(homerFile);
     // arr = makeHomer(mysteryFile);

      char[][] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr);
      displayFlippedHoriz(homerFile,newArr);
   }

   public static char[][] makeHomer(Scanner file)throws FileNotFoundException{
      file.hasNext();
      int height = file.nextInt();
      int width = file.nextInt();
      char [][] arr = new char [height][width];

      while (file.hasNext()){
         for (int rows=0; rows<width; rows++){
            for (int col = 0; col< height; col++){
               int currNum = file.nextInt();
               char character = (char)currNum;
               arr[rows][col] = character;          
               System.out.print(character);

               if(rows+1 == height){
                 System.out.println();
               }

            }
         }

      }
      return arr[][];

   }

   public static void displayFlippedHoriz(Scanner file, char newArr[][]){

      while (file.hasNext()){
         for (int rows = 0; rows< height; rows++){
            for (int col = arr.length; col<width; col--){
               currNum = file.nextInt();
               character = (char)currNum;
               System.out.print(character);
            }
         }
        if (rows+1 == height){
            System.out.println();
        }
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `arr[][]` means?

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the array itself after it's declared, there is no need for the `[]` characters.  Just use:

```
return arr;
```

The reason the error message though `.class` was coming is that the only way to make a valid expression out of `arr[][]` is to make a class literal out of it, e.g. `arr[][].class`.  That's not helpful, since `arr` isn't a class name anyway.